# php mysql insert value from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array.Now I want to insert data in my table using this array value. 
`$claw` is the array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Alabama
            [1] => Yes
            [2] => R
            [3] => 

are free to enact restrictions greater than .

            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 

It is unlawful to sell
        )
)
```

Now I want to insert data in my table using this array value.

I am using this code but not work

```
    public function Insert($claw)
    {


                $fields = array();
                for($i=0;$i<$claw; $i++) 
                {
                    for($j=0;$j<$claw[$i]; $j++) 
                    {               
                        $fields[] = $claw[$i][$j];
                    }
                }

                $sql = "Insert into information values(" . implode(', ', $fields) . ')';

return $this->MyCommandR($sql);


    }
```

I cant understand whats my wrong

Comment: You need to quote your values, and you should really escape them as well.

Comment: Problem 1: `$i<$claw` ... that doesn't seem right. Problem 2: Your insert values need quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the field to save these data 
    $sql = "Insert into information (`name`,`yes`,`ABC`,`CBA`) values(" . implode(', ', $fields) . ')';

or

```
$field = $conn->query("DESCRIBE  `".$table."`"); 
$constrantsQueryfield = array();
$constrantsQueryvalue = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($field))
{

if ($row['Field']!='ID' && $row['Key']!='PRI')
{
if (array_key_exists($row['Field'],$data))
{
if ($row['Key']=='DATE')
{
    $constrantsQueryfield[] = $row['Field'];
$constrantsQueryvalue[] = date("Y-m-d");
}
else
{
$constrantsQueryfield[] = $row['Field'];
$constrantsQueryvalue[] = $data[$row['Field']];
}
}
}
}
$constrantQuery = "INSERT INTO `".$table."` ";
for ($i = 0;$i<count($constrantsQueryfield);$i++)
{
if ($i == 0){
$constrantQuery .= "(";
}
$constrantQuery .= "`".$constrantsQueryfield[$i]."`";
if ($i+1 == count($constrantsQueryfield))
{
$constrantQuery .= ")";

}
else
{
    $constrantQuery .= ", ";

    }
}
$constrantQuery .= "  VALUES  ";
$contstantQuery .= "(" . implode(', ', $data) . ')'; // ANy data array

$conn->query($constrantQuery);
```